# Why am i getting java.net.SocketException while running the spark job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true") \
        .config("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", "true") \
        .config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "1024") \
        .getOrCreate()

data = [('James','','Smith','1991-04-01','M',3000),
        ('Michael','Rose','','2000-05-19','M',4000),
        ('Robert','','Williams','1978-09-05','M',4000),
        ('Maria','Anne','Jones','1967-12-01','F',4000),
        ('Jen','Mary','Brown','1980-02-17','F',-1)
        ]

columns = ["firstname","middlename","lastname","dob","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)

df.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), provide a brief introduction to your problem so others can understand and replicate it.

Comment: Can you please share the exact exception stack trace thrown?